# how to replace ffmeg's h.264 decoder?

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, decode, h.264

Since FFMPEG take too much CPU resource and we can hardware decode in IOS8 ,so i want to replace its decoder with  `hardware`decoder.

but how? i search in google but get nothing.

and my thought now is to replace this method with my decoder
    `_pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(m_pCodecCtx->codec_id);`

here is what i want:
1、if there is a way to replace the h.264 decoder?
2、if there exists,then how to do that?
3、if there any articles may help me?